# What is smart contract creation TX?

Tags: smartcontracts, truffle, ganache

I am beginner and begun my Solidity programming with Truffle and work with Ganache. Whenever i open `Contracts` item in Ganache there is a `CREATION TX` there. What means that exactly. Thank you for giving me a clear explanation about that.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VU36K.png)

Answer (score 0):

When you deploy contract to Ethereum, you are changing the Ethereum state. Changing state will create a tx in Ethereum.

Take a look at this contract creation tx [here](https://etherscan.io/tx/0x495402df7d45fe36329b0bd94487f49baee62026d50f654600f6771bd2a596ab).

- *0x495...6ab* is the tx that changed Ethereum state that 'registered' the contract in Ethereum
- *0xbaa...3f4* is the contract address

So, based on your image, *0x6aC...* is like *0x495...6ab* (creation tx) and *0x926...* is like *0xbaa...3f4* (contract address).